# Текст на картинке .bmp - перевести в string

Tags: c#, поиск-библиотек, распознавание-символов

Задача: `RU` Текст на картинке `.bmp` перевести в `string`

Белый фон - тёмный текст

Какую библиотеку на C# можно использовать для этого ?

Comment: гуглим Tesseract

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любую OCR.
Есть пример с Emgu.CV.OCR/Tesseract
Взято отсюда: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/ru/examples/Emgu.CV.OCR/Tesseract/GetCharacters/php-tesseract-getcharacters-method-examples.html

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\raw\classified\");
   //var img = new Image<Rgb, byte>(files[0]);
   var img = new Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Gray, byte>(@"d:\raw\classified\test.jpg");
   var _ocr = new Tesseract(@"D:\", "eng", OcrEngineMode.TesseractCubeCombined);
   _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "1234567890"); //походу это какой-то фильтр и он может быть необязательным
   _ocr.Recognize(img);
   var result = _ocr.GetCharacters();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EmguCV версии 4.1.1.3497
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже ссылка - надо скачать файл `rus.traineddata` - я разместил на диске `C:\`
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/rus.traineddata

Ну и вот код:

```
    private string ImgToText(string pathImg)
    {
        var img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(pathImg);
        Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract(@"C:\", "rus", OcrEngineMode.TesseractLstmCombined);
        tesseract.SetImage(img);
        tesseract.Recognize();
        var result = tesseract.GetUTF8Text();

        tesseract.Dispose();

        return result;
    }
```